# Getting handles of all controls on a window using it's classname

Tags: c#, .net, handle, hwnd, spy++

I can get handles using mouse location by clicking. But i need to find handles of all controls on a window using it's classname without clicking. I have to get them, while the window opened. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

you can combine two popular API's:

```
[DllImport("user32.Dll")]
private static extern Boolean EnumChildWindows(int hWndParent, PChildCallBack lpEnumFunc, int lParam);
```

This function is for getting all "child" windows inside a window. The second one is

```
[DllImport("User32.Dll")]
private static extern void GetClassName(int hWnd, StringBuilder s, int nMaxCount);
```

Use this method to filter whether the enummed window has a specific class name.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use a variety of API calls, starting with [EnumWindows](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumwindows) and probably [GetClassName](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/GetClassName.html) as well.